# How can you add paragraphs using a Direct SQL call in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using direct SQL (as that's all I have access to) I've tried to use this query but the output doesn't add a new line...

```
SELECT ('LINE 1' || CHR(13) || 'LINE 4') AS column_name;


Output: 
column_name
LINE 1 LINE 4
```

Does anyone know how to add a new line using Direct SQL?

Comment: Your code works fine although you don't need concat() if you use the || operator: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=178b30fd5ed82f7169efe72eca46c084 Maybe the tool that you use does not display the result as 2 lines.

Comment: We are using Postgres

Comment: @EthanT You need to use some tool to connect to Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

You will generally need char(10) not char(13).  Or if you are displaying your information directly in HTML, you will need `'<br>'`.

Comment: Ahh, thank you!  It's the '<br>' that worked.  I tried it earlier but without the quotes around it.  Thanks!